# How to get Fields from a MWStruct in C#

Tags: c#, matlab

I am trying to conver a matlab code to DLL and using in this DLL into C#.
The Matlab Code give the out put in the form of Structure Array as

```
Output= 
struct with fields:
Partion: [1×1 struct]
SWallR: [1×1 struct]
SWallL: [1×1 struct]
SWallB: [1×1 struct]
SWallF: [1×1 struct]
SWallC: [1×1 struct]
RWallR: [1×1 struct]
RWallL: [1×1 struct]
RWallB: [1×1 struct]
RWallF: [1×1 struct]
RWallC: [1×1 struct]
```

I have made a C# script as follows:

```
class Class1
{
public static void Measurements()
{
SoundInsulationClass obj = new SoundInsulationClass();
MWArray Output = obj.TestSoundInsulation();
Console.WriteLine(Output.IsStructArray);
Console.WriteLine(Output);
Console.ReadKey();
}
}
}
```

The Consol show the results as follows

```
True
Partion: [1x1 struct]
SWallR: [1x1 struct]
SWallL: [1x1 struct]
SWallB: [1x1 struct]
SWallF: [1x1 struct]
SWallC: [1x1 struct]
RWallR: [1x1 struct]
RWallL: [1x1 struct]
RWallB: [1x1 struct]
RWallF: [1x1 struct]
RWallC: [1x1 struct]
```

Now I want to acess the Fields of the Output.

Please help me to get the data of the field inside the array
main Output array is a structure and it also contains furter structures

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

The first one is to use [MWStructArray.GetField(String)](https://www.mathworks.com/help/dotnetbuilder/MWArrayAPI/html/M_MathWorks_MATLAB_NET_Arrays_MWStructArray_GetField.htm), which returns the contents of the specified field in the structure array. This is a good option if you have to iterate over the contents of a field. Let's suppose that your `Output` variable contains `10` elements and that `RWallC` contains numeric values... then `Output.GetField("RWallC")` will return a `MWArray` of size `10` as follows:

```
// the value of the field RWallC for the second structure of the array
MWArray rwc = Output.GetField("RWallC");
Double x = rwx[2].ToScalarDouble();
```

The second one is to use [MWStructArray.GetField(String, Int32)](https://www.mathworks.com/help/dotnetbuilder/MWArrayAPI/html/M_MathWorks_MATLAB_NET_Arrays_MWStructArray_GetField_1.htm), which returns the content of the specified field for the specified structure of an array of structures:

```
// the value of the field RWallC for the second structure of the array
Double x = Output.GetField("RWallC",2).ToScalarDouble();
```

I think that you can also use direct indexing, but I never tried:

```
Double x = Output["RWallC",2].ToScalarDouble();
```